# Infinite scroll is not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, infinite-scroll, ios7.1

I am using `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()` to trigger `Ajax` and load more contents on PC, but it's not working on iPhone. Then I found someone suggested using `>=` instead. However it's still not working on iPhone. And lots of questions about this problem on stackoverflow were asked and it seems like most of them were remaining un-answered. So I was wondering whether there is a simple solution but not a button to trigger the infinite scroll on phones.

**Update**: I found something that might be the cause. When I zoom out the page, safari (don't know how do other mobile browsers perform) does not resize the `$(window).height()`, so the scroll bar is never going to "reach the bottom" and trigger the `Ajax`. Is there any clues to resize the height?

Comment: Does this pertain to the touch interface itself or is your question addressing iOS Safari specifically? What iOS version?

Comment: Hi @AstroCB, I only have an iphone (ios 7) to test the web sites. I am not really sure how other devices perform.

Comment: Are you using Safari?